# Get Subdomains to Show Up As Referrals in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

In Google Analytics, no traffic from the various subdomains of my client's business is being reported as a referral.  It's very important for the business to understand which subdomains are pushing traffic to the main domain.  Right now, they're all showing up as Direct or Unknown.  How can I ensure that the subdomains are included as referrals?

**Hostnames (Domains) in Question**

- example.com (main marketing site)
- [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) (ALSO the main marketing site.  Unclear why it's showing up separately)
- blog.example.com (Blog site)
- app.example.com (Web platform)

**Referral Exclusion List**

- example.com

This is what's preventing the subdomains from showing up as referrals.  Can I somehow be more specific here to fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because GENERAL SEO QUESTIONS ARE OFF-TOPIC. Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on Webmasters.SE at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com. If someone has directed you here to read this warning, go back and delete your question.

Answer (score 1):

Google analytics by default tracks subdomains in the same property of root domain(example.com) if the same GA tracking code is placed on both root and subdomains.

Removing root domain (example.com) from Referral Exclusion List is not a good practice, this may cause other impacts on your reports.

If you want to get your subdomain as referral in you reports(as per your business requirement), place different GA tracking codes on subdomains than root domain.

Comment: Thank you, Vyankatesh.  I agree with what you said, yet my client has unfortunately set it up this way (with the GA tracking code on multiple domains) because they specifically want to track how users move from one domain to the another and track specific interactions between them.An example flow might be:

- User hits example.com/ from Organic Google search result
- User goes to app.example.com/signup
- User fills out signup form on app.example.com/signup

How could you remove the tracking code while reporting on this workflow in the main GA account? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a referral report consider analysing the flow of users instead. Add a filter which adds domain to your page reports. You will then be easily able to analyse how users move around the site. You can also obtain the same effect by using the hostname dimension which should contain the different sub domains.
This is the filter to show full URL: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012243?hl=en